# how to add datasource from different tables to the multiple merge fields present in the document

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my document i have merge fields from the different table columns,how to merge the data source from the different tables into the document..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try to create [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). For example -

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Person 
AS
    SELECT 
          e.EmployeeID
        , e.TabelNumber
        , FullName = p.SName + N' ' + p.FName + N' ' + p.ThirdName
    FROM dbo.Employee e
    JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.PersonID = e.PersonID
```

Comment: Did this be helpful for you?

Comment: Before writing the view first i have to know the what merge field present in the document,i have nearly 1000 documents,the merge fields are from different table column names..Example <<ClientName>> from client table,<<MatterCode>> from Matter Table like i have 1000 of fields,how to find them and add bookmark data to the merge fields..please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide DDL for your tables.